# Changing colors on bokeh patches plot real time

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to create a bokeh plot of the US States, and color each of the state according to some data. Now using [this](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/texas.html) tutorial I managed to create this, but I also want to enhance it, and add a slider to it, to change the values displayed. For example like displaying separate years.

With the help of [this](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/slider.html) tutorial, I managed to add the slider, and the underlying data does change, according to the hover text, but the colors aren't recalculated, and so the visual representation does not match the values.

This is the code I've used, from a Jupyter notebook, so anybody who wants to try can reproduce

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import (
    ColumnDataSource,
    HoverTool,
    LogColorMapper,
    Range1d, CustomJS, Slider
)
from bokeh.palettes import Inferno256 as palette
from bokeh.plotting import figure

from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox

from bokeh.sampledata.us_counties import data as counties
from bokeh.sampledata.us_states import data as states
from bokeh.sampledata.unemployment import data as unemployment
import pandas as pd
import random
output_notebook()
palette.reverse()

states_accumulated ={}
available_state_codes = states.keys()

for key, value in counties.items():
    state_name = value["state"].upper()
    if state_name in states.keys() and "number" not in states[state_name]:
        states[state_name]["number"] = key[0]

for key,state in states.items():
    state["code"] = key

state_list = []

for key,state in states.items():
    state_list.append(state)

unemployment_transf = []
for key,value in unemployment.items():
    unemployment_transf.append({
        "State":key[0],
        "County":key[1],
        "Value":value
    })
unemp_df = pd.DataFrame(unemployment_transf)
unemp_sum = unemp_df.groupby("State").mean()["Value"]
unemp_sum = unemp_sum.sort_index()

unemp_sum_flat = {key:value for key, value in unemp_sum.items()}

for state in state_list:
    state["value"] = unemp_sum_flat[state["number"]]
state_df = pd.DataFrame(state_list)
color_mapper = LogColorMapper(palette=palette)

state_xy = (list(state_df["lons"].values),list(state_df["lats"].values))

max_x = max([max(l) for l in state_xy[0]])
max_y = max([max(l) for l in state_xy[1]])
min_x = min([min(l) for l in state_xy[0]])
min_y = min([min(l) for l in state_xy[1]])

data=dict(
    x=state_xy[0],
    y=state_xy[1],
    name=list(state_df["name"].values),
    used = list(state_df["value"].values)
)

data['1999'] = list(state_df["value"].values)
data['2000'] = [random.randrange(0,10) for i in range(len(state_xy[0]))]
source = ColumnDataSource(data)

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,reset,hover,save"

p = figure(
    title="States", tools=TOOLS,
    x_axis_location=None, y_axis_location=None
)
p.width=450
p.height = 450
p.x_range= Range1d(-170,-60)
p.y_range = Range1d(min_y-10,max_y+10)
p.grid.grid_line_color = None

renderer = p.patches('x', 'y', source=source,
          fill_color={'field': 'used', 'transform': color_mapper},
          fill_alpha=0.7, line_color="white", line_width=0.5)


hover = p.select_one(HoverTool)
hover.point_policy = "follow_mouse"
hover.tooltips = [
    ("Name", "@name"),
    ("Unemployment rate)", "@used%"),
    ("(Long, Lat)", "($x, $y)"),
]

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source,plot=p,color_mapper = color_mapper,renderer = renderer), code="""
    var data = source.data;
    var year = year.value;
    used = data['used']
    should_be = data[String(year)]
    for (i = 0; i < should_be.length; i++) {
        used[i] = should_be[i];
    } 
""")


year_slider = Slider(start=1999, end=2000, value=1999, step=1,
                    title="year", callback=callback)
callback.args["year"] = year_slider

layout = row(
    p,
    widgetbox(year_slider),
)
show(layout)
```

Sample images of the plot:
[image: First visualization]
[image: Second visualization]

What I would like to accomplish, is that when I change the slider, the colors on the plot should change. Now I think the JS callback should call some kind of redraw or recalculate, but I haven't found any documentation about it. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

append `source.change.emit()` to the Javascipt code to trigger the change event.

Comment: For me, `source.change.emit()` does not do anything, and in the JS console, I get an error, saying `TypeError: source.change is undefined`


Though using `source.trigger("change")` does seem to solve it.

Comment: @Brabulla Your bokeh version is old, if you update to the newest version, you need to change `source.trigger('change')` to `source.change.emit()`.

Comment: Thank you, the update solved it, I was using 0.12.7, and now that I've updated to 0.12.11, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Appending `source.trigger("change");` to the CustomJS seems to solve the problem, now as the slider changes, the colors change.